# jQuery Validator not working for upper validation

Tags: jquery-validate

I am validating two sections of a webpage the first validation section validates however the second validator is not for some reason.

```
$(function(){



/* first validation - works*/
jVal = {
    //validate firstName
    'firstName': function(){

        //appends #firstNameInfo with .info to body
        $('body').append('<div id="firstNameInfo" class="info"></div>');

        //create variables
        var firstNameInfo = $('#firstNameInfo');
        var ele = $('#firstName');

        var patt = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]{1,20}$/; 

        if(!patt.test(ele.val())) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            firstNameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        }else{
            firstNameInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },

    //validate lastName
    'lastName': function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="lastNameInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var lastNameInfo = $('#lastNameInfo');
        var ele =$('#lastName');

        var patt = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]{1,20}$/;

        if(!patt.test(ele.val())){
            jVal.errors = true;
                lastNameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
                ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        }else{
            lastNameInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    //validate phone

    'phone' : function(){
        $('body').append('<div id="phoneInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var phoneInfo = $('#phoneInfo');
        var ele = $('#phone');

        var patt = /^((\+?1-)?\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$/;

        if(!patt.test(ele.val())) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            phoneInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        }else{
            phoneInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },

    //validate zipcode 
    'zip' : function() {
        $('body').append('<div id="zipInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var zipInfo = $("#zipInfo");
        var ele = $('#content_form #zip');

        var patt = /^\d\d\d\d\d$/;

        if(!patt.test(ele.val())){
            jVal.errors = true;
                zipInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
                ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        }else{
            zipInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    //submit button code
    'sendForm':function(){
        if(!jVal.errors){
            $('#content_form').submit();
        }
    },
};

$('#content_form #submit').click(function(){
    var obj = $.browser.webkit ? $('body') : $('html');
    jVal.errors = false;
    jVal.firstName();
    jVal.lastName();
    jVal.phone();
    jVal.zip();
    jVal.sendForm();

return false;

$('#firstName').change(jVal.firstName);
$('#lastName').change(jVal.lastName);
$('#email').change(jVal.email);
$('#content_form #zip').change(jVal.zip);

});
```

/********** Second Validation Does Not work ************/

```
kVal ={

    'zip' : function() {
        $('body').append('<div id="Infozip" class="info"></div>');

        var Infozip = $("#Infozip");
        var ele = $('#form #zip');

        var patt = /^\d\d\d\d\d$/;

        if(!patt.test(ele.val())){
            kVal.error = true;
                Infozip.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
                ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        }else{
            Infozip.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    //submit button code
    'send':function(){
        if(!kVal.errors){
            $('#form').submit();
        }
    },
};

$('#form button#submit').click(function(){
    var obj = $.browser.webkit ? $('body') : $('html');
    kVal.errors = false;
    kVal.zip();
    kVal.send();

return false;


$('#form #zip').change(kVal.zip);
});


}); /*main function closer*/
```

HTML FOR FIRST Validation -WORKING -

```
<div id="content_form">
            <p>
                <label class="block">
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" type="firstName" autocomplete="on" value="first name">
                </label>
                <label class="block">
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" type="lastName" autocomplete="on" value="last name">
                </label>
                <label class="block">
                    <input type="text" id="phone" type="phone" autocomplete="on" value="phone">
                </label>
                <label class="block">
                    <input type="text" id="zip" type="zip" autocomplete="on" value="zip code">
                </label> 
                <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" title="submit">submit</button>
            </p>
        </div><!-- end form -->
```

HTML FOR SECOND Validation

```
<div id="form">
            <p>
                <label class="block">
                    <input type="text" id="zip" type="zip" autocomplete="on" value="zip code">
                </label> 
                <button type="submit"  id="submit" value="CHECK NOW" title="check now">check now</button>
            </p>        
        </div><!-- end form -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same `id` on both zip fields, which is probably causing your problems. The docs for [the jQuery `#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) has this to say;

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, **queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM**. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

That is, your selection in `$('#form #zip').change(kVal.zip);` will not use the hierarchy under `#form` to find `#zip`, it will still find the first instance in the entire  DOM.

Comment: Thank you for helping me resolve my dilemma. I noticed that my validation script only works in IE10 - IE8 but does not work at all in IE7. What changes must i make in order to get this running in IE7?

Comment: @user1584751 Sorry, don't have an IE7 to test with. If you need help with that, you should probably ask a new question, that will get more attention than a question in a comment on an existing question.